# Variational principle, functional gradient

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hamiltonian, variational-principle, functional-derivatives

Given the energy functional 
$$E[\Psi] = \frac{\langle \Psi \vert H \vert \Psi \rangle}{\langle \Psi \vert \Psi \rangle},$$ its functional gradient is
$$\frac{\delta E[\Psi]}{\delta \langle \Psi \vert}=\frac{H\vert \Psi \rangle -E[\Psi]\vert \Psi \rangle}{\langle \Psi \vert \Psi \rangle}.$$

I do not understand how to obtain this expression. What it the rule to evaluate a functional gradient of the function $E[\Psi]$?

Comment: You might get better help if you detailed how you understand the derivative of a scalar involving vectors with respect to a vector.

Comment: Is this taken from a reference?

Answer (score 1):

OP's formula seems to be the natural functional generalization of the partial derivative 
$$\frac{\partial E(z,z^{\dagger})}{\partial z^{\dagger}}~\stackrel{(2)}{=}~\frac{(H-E(z,z^{\dagger}))z}{z^{\dagger}z},\tag{1}$$
where 
$$E(z,z^{\dagger})~=~\frac{z^{\dagger}Hz}{z^{\dagger}z},\tag{2}$$
and where the variables $z$ and $z^{\dagger}$ are treated as independent.

Comment: thank you a lot! You're right..I just got puzzled 
foolishly